# Could we use "thank you too" instead of saying "you're welcome"?

Tags: grammar, politeness

Could we use "thank you too" for the response to someone has thanked us?
Is it grammatically correct to use that?

Comment: You can use anything you like. But this is about customary behaviour, and "Thank you too" is not a customary way of acknowledging thanks, though we certainly may say it in some contexts. (Sixty years ago, when I was young, "You're welcome" was something those funny Americans said. We funny British didn't really have a conventional phrase for it - the traditional one was "not at all", but that was old-fashioned).

Comment: Using "thank you too" invites a chain of saying "thank you" for saying "thank you" for saying ... . "Thank you too" is usually used when A has done something for B and B has done something for A. One would say "Thank you" and the other "Thank you too". I've come across "don't mention it" as a response to thanks, but in these informal times I am more likely to say "that's OK".

Comment: @ColinFine - my father used to say 'Pray don't mention it', and, as is the way of things, I find myself adopting those of his habits that I used to sneer at. This one does get me  odd looks sometimes (not always).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: yes, of course. I thiought there was a traditional response I was missing, but I couldn't think of it. "Don't mention it" was the most common option.

Comment: @ColinFine  If I was very sure of my company, I might say 'Madame, je vous en prie' but I think that's a bit OT for here. I know a confirmed Americanophile who says 'de nada'.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the situation, I guess, but in most cases, saying that would be rather unnatural. We usually say “thank you” when someone has done something for us, and we wish to express gratitude for that action. In other words, it’s usually **a one-sided remark**. “You’re welcome,” “no problem,” and other variations used as a response to thanks express a sentiment that said action was no big deal.

> **A: Thank you for cooking this meal for me.** (expresses gratitude for person B’s cooking)
>
> **B: You’re welcome! It was no problem at all.** (expresses that person A is welcome to ask them to cook again)

Thus, saying “thank you too” as a response would not usually make very much sense, because it’s not clear what you’re thanking the person back for. Going back to the example above, it wouldn’t make sense for person B to thank person A for anything, really, because person A didn’t actually do any sort of action.

Answer (score 2):

"Thank you too" is a common response where both people have helped the other, and one thanks the other, and the other returns the thanks because they're also grateful.

Comment: Yes. I'd add a couple examples where this is common, at least in America, would be interactions with cashiers, waiters, and customer service people generally. At the end of a transaction they might say "Thanks," and in that case "Thank you" or "Thank you too" would be much more appropriate than either "You're welcome" or "No problem."

Comment: @Katy Thanks! I think your comment covers it well